# Automatic connection to known WIFI Hotspot

Tags: java, android, wifi

I'm creating an Android app for my school. I want my app to connect automatically (with the students ID and password) to the school hotspot.

Can anyone give me hints about that? I don't know exactly how the hotspot work. Students usually connect by a webportal.

Thanks you for your help :)

Matthieu

Comment: Apps do not connect to hotspots. Your device should connect to that hotspot automatically if the user once connected with it.

Comment: The problem is that the device connect automatically to the network but can access the internet only with the good credentials :) (which must be set using a webpage :) )

Comment: OK. Then post the right data to that webpage as that webpage will contain a form which has to be filled in with username and password i presume. But if you dont tell how would we know?

Comment: Yes, that was obvious and I'm not good at explaining my problems :)

Thanks :)